# Is it possible to make pygame work with a slightly newer version of python?

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.5

When I run a simple pygame script, I get an error:

```
 from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

After looking at stack overflow posts, it seems that this error occurs due to mismatch between pygame and python. The latest Python is 3.5.2. The latest pygame is 1.9.2 and it works with pygame 3.4 or older.

Could it still be possible to make the combination of py 3.5.2 and pygame 1.9.2 work, perhaps by changing some config file or getting the missing dll or something else ?

Chenqui.

Comment: it can't find DLL files so maybe it can't find [SDL 1.2 library](https://www.libsdl.org) (created in C/C++) which you have to install first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find pygame 1.9.2 for python 3.5 here: 
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame 
I'm not exactly good with configuring files, so there might be another way that might be more elegant, but this seems to be among the easiest ways.